# How to exclude rows based on grepl special character using dplyr piping

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```r
library(tidyverse)
ndf <- structure(list(experiment_status = c("Negative？", "Negative？", 
"Negative", "Negative？", "Negative？", "Negative？"), id = 1:6), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))

ndf
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   experiment_status    id
#>   <chr>             <int>
#> 1 Negative？            1
#> 2 Negative？            2
#> 3 Negative              3
#> 4 Negative？            4
#> 5 Negative？            5
#> 6 Negative？            6
```

What I want to do is to filter the rows keeping only those **without** a question mark `?`, i.e. only row 3 is preserved after pipe.

Why did this fail?

```r
  ndf %>% 
    filter(!grepl("[?]", experiment_status))
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: Are there supposed to be spaces following the `?`. Copy/pasting your example seems to generate something that isn't an ASCII `?`.

Comment: That is not a question mark. That is a fullwidth question mark with ascii value 65311 or rather

Comment: @Onyambu how can  I convert that into ASCII based under pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there is a problem happened during import the `csv` file which is written in a non-English OS.

```
> '？' =='?'
[1] FALSE

ndf %>% filter(!grepl('？',experiment_status))

#Try removing white space but it fails
> trimws(ndf$experiment_status,'both')
[1] "Negative？" "Negative？" "Negative"   "Negative？" "Negative？" "Negative？"
#Change '？' to '?' using gsub
> gsub('？', '?', ndf$experiment_status)
[1] "Negative?" "Negative?" "Negative"  "Negative?" "Negative?" "Negative?"


ndf %>% mutate(experiment_status_clean = gsub('？', '?', experiment_status))

#Now you are search for a litteral ? so you need to escape ? using \\
ndf %>% mutate(experiment_status_clean = gsub('？', '?', experiment_status)) %>% 
        filter(!grepl('\\?',experiment_status_clean))
```

Comment: how can I change  `'？` into `'?'` in the dplyr pipe? or clean the `experiment status`

Comment: how to do `gsub` and `trimws` with pipe?

Comment: No need for `trimws` as it fails, I used because I thought there is a space after '？', but there wasn't.

Comment: I tried to put together. Why this failed `ndf %>% 
  mutate(experiment_status_clean = gsub('？', '?', experiment_status)) %>% 
  filter(!grepl('?',experiment_status_clean))`

Answer (score 2):

```
 ndf %>% 
     filter(!grepl(intToUtf8(65311), experiment_status))
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  experiment_status    id
  <chr>             <int>
1 Negative              3
```

One thing you also notice is if you coerce the tibble to dataframe, it will give you its hex-Unicode which is `<U+FF1F>`. You can also use this to filter.

ie:

```
ndf %>% 
     filter(!grepl(intToUtf8(0xFF1F), experiment_status))
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  experiment_status    id
  <chr>             <int>
1 Negative              3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ndf %>% 
  filter(!grepl("?", experiment_status, fixed = TRUE))
```

But in your example I think `filter(experiment_status == "Negative")` would work too.

EDIT: or since we can have "Positive" too -

```
ndf %>% 
  filter(experiment_status %in% c("Negative", "Positive"))
```

Comment: In actuality it also contains `Positive？`

Comment: So it's always helpful to include all the expected cases in your examples :)

Comment: My question in the comments is whether it's _supposed_ to be a question mark.

Answer (score 1):

To clean your interrogation marks you can use `stringi::stri_trans_general`. I'd suggest you use it as early as possible on your data to avoid bad surprises.

```
library(stringi)
ndf %>%
  mutate_at("experiment_status", stri_trans_general, "latin-ascii") %>%
  filter(!grepl("[?]", experiment_status)) # or filter(!grepl("\\?$", experiment_status))

# A tibble: 1 x 2
#     experiment_status    id
#                 <chr> <int>
#   1          Negative     3
```

Here no knowledge about the problematic character is needed, and you might clean by the same token other unfortunate punctuation signs or alternate characters.